# Unable to download from https Sharepoint online with SSIS

Tags: https, ssis, sharepoint-2013

I am struggling with this task. I need to download one file (excel) from SharePoint online and I cant install extra features so I am trying do it in HTTP connection.

The problem is that HTTP connection in SSIS give me code error 403 and I don't understand what to fix it.

I have an Microsoft account in SharePoint where I have permissions. I am using HTTP connection manager editor with credentials but I am not sure if the domain is right.

Comment: Please include the details of your http request in your question.

Comment: Hello, which details do you want? Thanks

Comment: URL and headers would be a start. You need to include enough detail so that anyone can reproduce your error.

Comment: Describe where you see the error (while editing the connection manager or executing it).  Describe how you are executing the package (in debug, from server, dtexec).  What version of SSIS?  How is the package configured, i.e. where is it getting connection information from?  What's the protection level.

Comment: 403 is a 'forbidden' error. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403. Your URL is probably valid but you probably need to login first. If the site is https, clearly you cannot use a http url.

Answer (score 1):

Took me quite a while to get to grips with this so for anyone else who is struggling, the following worked for me:

```
    Using wc As New WebClient
        wc.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(usr, spwd)
        wc.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
        wc.DownloadFile(source, target)
    End Using
```

Specifically, I needed to use `SharePointOnlineCredentials` rather than `System.Net.NetworkCredential`, and was still getting the 403 error until I added the wc.Headers.Add() line.

For info, I'm using:

- Visual Studio 2015
- SSDT for Visual Studio 2015
- SQLServer 2016
- SharePoint Online Client Components SDK(http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

So for completeness, the other bits you need are:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Security
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
...
 Dim pwd As String = "password"
 Dim cpwd As Char() = pwd.ToCharArray()
 Dim spwd As New SecureString()
 For Each c As Char In cpwd
      spwd.AppendChar(c)
 Next
```

Comment: As this is a 6 year old post and Nick Noodle only has 11 total posts I'm not expecting an answer :), but where did you put this? In the Script Component as a part of the script?